# Implement data from the database to input field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, edit

I am trying to send data from database when pressing Edit on ActionLink(Last line on view). Having some problem in view Controller to understand how this data will be sent to the right input field so i can Edit it and send it back to database.
(This Question is only for the GET part so i have not included Post controller)

### View(view name AddCourse):

```
@model IEnumerable<CadProject.Models.CourseModel>

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddCourse", "AdminModel", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Emnekode", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input name="CourseCode" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Emne", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input name="CourseName" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>

   <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
}

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CourseCode)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CourseName)
        </th>
        <th>
            Edit/Delete
        </th>
    </tr>

    @if (Model != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CourseCode)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CourseName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }

</table>
```

### View controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    db.Courses.Find(id);

    CourseModel model = db.Courses.Find(id);
    if(model == null)
    {
        return View();
    }
    return View("AddCourse", db.Courses);
}
```

### Database model:

```
public class CourseModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string CourseCode { get; set; }

    public string CourseName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It not really clear what your doing here. Which view is that (its model is a collection which suggests it the `Index` view for displaying all existing `CourseModel`) - but why does it then have a form (and a form which is not even strongly typed to the model). And `@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id })` would not make any sense unless its in a loop

Comment: thanks for your input, I am sorry that i have forgotten part of the code. Have I made this question clearer for you? :)

Comment: Your view does not make sense, nor does your `Edit` method which needs to returns an `Edit.cshtml` view which should have `@model CourseModel` and a form with `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CourseName)` etc (although even that's bad practice and you should be using a view model, not the data model)

Answer (score 0):

The functionality the Edit(HttpGet) method is to take the ID of the item the user want's to edit, find **ONE** record in the database with this ID and send the found record to the Edit view where you have various controls that display the current values and allow the user to change them through the use of text boxes e.t.c

In the code you posted you look up the course the user wants to edit but then you return all the courses to the Edit view, which is wrong.It's supposed to be like this:

public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        db.Courses.Find(id);

```
    CourseModel model = db.Courses.Find(id);
    if(model == null)
    {
        return View();
    }
    return View("EditCourse", model);
}
```

Have a look at this simple example:

**Edit Action:**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var course1 = new Course { ID = 0, Name = "Software Engineering" };
    var course2 = new Course { ID = 1, Name = "ASP.NET MVC" };
    var course3 = new Course { ID = 2, Name = "C# Course" };

    var courses = new List<Course> { course1 ,course2, course3};

    var course = courses.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ID == id);

    return View("EditCourse",course);
}
```

**EditCourse View:**

```
@model Example.Models.Course

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EditCourse";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Course</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```